# SQL Server: использование FORMATFILE в bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

В SQL Server создана таблица

```
create table tbl (Id int, [Date] date, Notes nvarchar(max))
```

Для загрузки данных в таблицу tbl создал tbl.fmt

```
12.0
3
1   SQLINT      0   4   ","     1   Id      ""
2   SQLDATETIME 0   8   ","     2   Date    ""
3   SQLCHAR     0   0   "\r\n"  3   Notes   ""
```

Следующий код

```
bulk insert tbl from 'd:\tbl.txt'
with (
  firstrow = 2,
  DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
  FORMATFILE = 'd\tbl.fmt',
  tablock
)
```

для файла d:\tbl.txt

```
Id,  Date,           Notes
"1", "2016-01-01",   "какой-то текст"
```

выдает ошибку:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Как сделать правильно загрузку с помощью FORMATFILE?

Comment: префикс 1 выставить и длину у значений поменять для даты 10 , а разделитель "". указать параметр  -t для bcp (это запятая в качестве разделителя). 3 колонка - задать длину

Comment: 8 заменил на 10, а про префикс не пойму что делать?

Answer (score 1):

test.txt (подготовьте правильный файл с данными)

```
Id,Date,Note
1,2016-01-01,какой-то текст
```

test.fmt (для него соответствующий файл форматирования)

```
10.0
3
1   SQLCHAR     0   4   ","     1   Id      ""
2   SQLCHAR     0   10  ","     2   Date    ""
3   SQLCHAR     0   100 "\r\n"  3   Notes   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
```

проверяем:

```
SELECT *
      FROM  OPENROWSET (
        BULK  'd:\MSSQL\test.txt',
        FORMATFILE='d:\MSSQL\test.fmt',
        FIRSTROW=2   
      ) as t;
```

а уж потом вставляйте с преобразованием полей в нужную таблицу